# Multiple Choice Questions and certifications ones

Tags: discussion, off-topic

As read in many part of this site, them are off topic. I'm asking if that policy shall be reconsidered:

- networking certifications questions are useful (I hope!) to better understand
  how networking work
- if someone is studying for it, at sure is
  involved on the topics of this site
- in the medium period the ones that now are looking for network certify shall be working in this technology branch, and if they become frequent user of this site, they shall share here them competence.

And and everything else... so if was possible to "tolerate" them, maybe correctly tagged as `Multiple Choice Questions`, `certifications question` or something else, I think it will help to approach the network engineer of tomorrow and share with them your competence. Cheer

Comment: Certification questions and multiple choice topics have already been discussed at length [here](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/9666/network-engineering-to-include-discussion-of-certifications), [here](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/45/775) and [here](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/225/what-is-on-topic-lets-improve-our-faq-help/237#237).  The overwhelming consensus is not to allow them.

Comment: thanks for the reply @mike I read some of them before to ask. I decided to ask only for this reason: In more or less all of them was explained why is better no, I would explain a different prospective. Tx for your work here. Cheers

Comment: mmm... I was thinking to hijack that kind of questions in a stack exchange chat, but the low reputation of the news user doesn't permit it... maybe StackExchange isn't really the better place for that kind of use. Amen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the purposes of this answer, let's consider two possible categories of questions:

**A-questions**. There is a legitimate need for the questions we have already listed as [on-topic](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); furthermore, Stack Exchange offers useful improvements over many network engineering resources which are traditionally mailing lists (i.e. [cisco-nsp](https://puck.nether.net/pipermail/cisco-nsp/) and such).
**B-questions**. There already are [plenty of certification forums](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9687/37588) for asking about your homework, or why this cert practice exam prefers this answer to the multiple choice question.

It is very simple to come up with reasonable *B-questions*; no thought is involved, just copy your homework questions onto the site, or farm them from your favorite certification forum and change a few numbers / words.

Given that *B-questions* are so easy to write, and [reputation points](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) / [badges](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/help/badges) are at stake, *B-questions* will overwhelm this site and drown out the *A-questions*.

### Summary

Nothing has changed.  We want *A-questions*, we don't want *B-questions*.